# Fire Method when clicking tab Angular 2

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, tabs, ng-bootstrap

Hi im using this Tabs for Angular 2 . https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples

I want to know if there is a way to call a method when clicking on the tab...

something like this (not working) :

```
<ngb-tabset>

<ngb-tab (click)="Method()" title="my Tab">


      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <ng-template>

<ngb-tab>

<ngb-tabset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead you can add **ngbTabTitle** template and catch click event there:

```
<ngb-tab>
  <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
      <div (click)="Method()">my Tab</div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbTabContent>    
  </ng-template>
<ngb-tab>
```